# drop down list not appearing again 

Tags: html

I have two radio buttons what I want is that when I select one of them then a drop down list should appear and when other one is marked then drop down list should disappear and instead of it a text message should be displayed.

The code for this part is as follows --

```
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function showhide(r){
            var t=r.form['mode'];
            if (r.value=='none') {
                 t.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                 document.getElementById('data').innerHTML="option not supported";         

            }
            else {  
                    t.removeAttribute('disabled');

            }
            t.style.display=r.value;
            }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td width="400" height="40">Protocol</td>
            <td>
                 <table width="100%" name="table">
                 <tr>
                 <td style="text-align:center">
                 <input type="radio" name="protocol" value="" id="opt1" align="left" checked="checked" onclick="showhide(this)" />opt1
                 </td>

                 <td style="text-align:center">
                 <input type="radio" name="protocol" value="none" id="opt2" align="right" onclick="showhide(this)"/>opt2
                 </td>

                 </tr>
                 </table>

              </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td width="400" height="40">Mode of Operation</td>
              <td id="data">
                 <select name="mode"  id="mode">
                      <option value="opt1">TCP</option>
                      <option value="opt2">UDP</option>
                 </select>

              </td>
              </tr>
              </table>  
         </bdoy>
```

Now the text message ("option not supported") is displayed once and then it doesn't disappear when switching between the radio buttons and so drop down list doesn't appear again.Where am i getting wrong?? If possible make correction in the code.
Please correct me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <td name="data">
```

must be

```
 <td id="data">
```

Comment: ohkkkk....I changed the attribute name to 'id' but now that drop down list appears once at starting and after the text is displayed it becomes permanant..and doesn't disappear and the drop down list doesn't appear.

Comment: Yes, i just correct html for your javascript. If you want to show again select, you sholdn't change innerHTML, but hide select and show it when option supported.

Comment: but I have already added the line below else t.style.display=r.value  i think it shud wrk.Also if its wrong then also as far i know hiding can be done using display:none but what to use for showing it again.

Comment: after you change innerHTML for td there is no more radio in it.